# Shell script how to read input from a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection, input

I need to read input from a file given in following format.

```
$ ./process_data.sh arg1 < input_data.txt
```

How do I read `input_data` in my shell script `process_data.sh`?

Comment: The question is much too vague.  Read [Bash FAQ 01](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) about processing lines from input and come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 4):

In such usage there are several ways to read it:
while construction (will output argument and each string of file input_data.txt)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
while read STRING
do
    echo $STRING
done
```

awk (will output argument and second and third column of file input data)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
awk '{print $2" "$3}'
```

and so on. You can use sed, cut and many other unix utilities like in examples. Chose of utility depends on how you need to transform input data.
Of course you can change examples as you want.

Good luck =)

Answer (score 1):

In your process_data.sh you can write below code

```
while read line
do
   #work on data
done < `cat input_data.txt`
```

Comment: Have you even tried this?