# Using a file as an input to a script

Tags: shell-script, pipe

Say I want to use the name of a file as input, and process it with a pre-made script in a certain directory. How do I do it?

```
fileName < /folder1/scriptName
```

is this the right format?

Comment: or rather /folder1/scriptName < fileName(input)

Comment: yes, you can do that. Use `./path/to/script < file_name`.

Comment: thanks, do you know if you can use a directory instead of a file name as the parameter?

Comment: a directory is a file in linux, so i think it should work. you should use commands which work on directories. If you need any other help in this matter, comment or edit your question. Otherwise if an answer solves your problem, accept it

Comment: there is a similar question asked here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36621/shell-script-how-to-read-input-from-a-file. Read this for info: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name of the file as a parameter to the script

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript.sh
FILENAME=$1

echo "This is the filename:" $FILENAME
```

Then this is how you will call the script

```
./myscript.sh thisfile.txt
```

This will be the output for the script

```
This is the filename: thisfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the tests I executed:

```
$ vi scriptName.sh
#!/bin/bash
cat
```

Then executed,

```
$ ./scriptName < fileName
```

It will print the contents of the file.

This is a very basic example and the input is used only in one place. If you are processing the input in more than one place, which is usually the case when you write a script, then you will have to use the answer given by Fazle.